# not all malloc'ed memory is "heap" and each block is not contiguous in virtual memory?

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-memory-allocation, virtual-memory

It seems that `malloc` calls `mmap` internally as :

```
//not 100% correct onlyfor demo purpose
// void *mmap(void *start, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);

void *malloc(size_t size){
  ...
  mmap(NULL, size,...);   
  ...           
}
```

so  `malloc` passes `NULL` as the first argument for `mmap` as starting address, so the kernel will choose a suitable virtual address for the mapping, which means `malloc` will not necessarily create a mapping in the heap area(indicated by `brk` pointer).
[image]

If this is true, that means there will be a lot of gaps between each block in virtual memory after multiple `malloc` calls since each `malloc` return a new virtual address which is not contiguous to previous one, and those virtual addresses has nothing to do with `brk`, So once we free one particular block, then we cannot coalesce adjacent free blocks with the one we freed since each block is not contiguous in virtual memory, then isn't this dynamic memory allocation very inefficient?

Comment: How many terabytes of memory does your 64-bit CPU have?  How much address space can a 64-bit CPU address?  Suppose you have a mere 16 TiB of memory; that uses 1/1024th (less than 0.1%) of the possible address space.  You aren't going to run into problems for a while.  And if you only have 16 GiB of memory, you're talking about 1/1024 of the space that a 16 TiB machine uses — you're using an even tinier fraction of the address space.

Comment: The "heap" is a logical concept - the diagram you posted conflates actual memory obtained from the OS via `brk`/`sbrk` with the logical concept of a "heap".  "Heap" memory is whatever memory the implementation wants to use to satisfy calls to `malloc()`, `calloc()`, etc.  The [Hoard memory allocator](http://hoard.org/) uses multiple pools of memory for its "heap", for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for using `mmap` in `malloc` for **large blocks** is exactly that when the block is freed it can be reclaimed by the *OS* when it is `munmap`ped.

This is unlike the standard brk/sbrk "heap" where it is hardly ever possible to move the program break down, just because the heap is used for exactly for the reason that the allocations/deallocations need not happen in exact LIFO order - then your only hope is try to coalesce adjacent free memory blocks...

Comment: AAntti Haapala Thanks for your great answer, I think I'm almost there. soI found that for small allocation, `malloc` calls `brk` internally, and for large allocation,  `malloc` calls `mmap` internally, which makes sense to me now.  But when we call `free` to unallocate a block, then how does the allocator know this block was origianlly obtained from `mmap` or `brk`? becuase I think the allocator needs to distinguish them

Comment: @slowjams — The allocation code keeps track of chunks of memory and knows which ones were allocated with `mmap()` and which with `sbrk()` (or `brk()`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for your answer. so just to confirm,  `free` calls `munmap` or `brk` internally for blocks obtained from `mmap` or `brk` respectively?

Comment: Typically, it can call `munmap()` for blocks that were allocated with `mmap()`, but it cannot release memory back to the o/s that was allocated via `brk()` or `sbrk()`.